# Get substring of href attribute via css

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, substring

I am expanding URLs for a print stylesheet. The trouble is, some of the anchors reference JavaScript URLs, such as:

```
javascript:HandleLink('{{ reference ID }},'CPNEWWIN:_blank^@CP___PAGEID=12345678,{{ relative URL }}');
```

I know I can use substring matching attribute selectors to match the href attribute with code like `a[href^="/"]` or `a[href*=""]`, which is what I'm doing for other cases.

What I want to do here is get the URL out of that `CPNEWWIN:_blank^@CP___PAGEID=12345678,{{ relative URL }}` mess above.

Comment: You're printing....why does it matter?

Comment: [tag:css] can't get substrings from an attribute (or anything else), it can only select an element based on the substring of an attribute.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidThomas. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.